# Show that if $\lim(a_n-b_n)=0$ then not necessarily $\lim(a_n)=\lim(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to find a counter example. I would really appreciate some help. I know it's true if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent and if $a_n=b_n$ when they are divergent. But I am pretty certain there is a counter example

Comment: what makes you think that there is a counter-example?

Comment: $a_n=\sin n$ and $b_n=a_n$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson: clearly, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)\neq 0$

Comment: it's true if at least one of the two sequences is convergent.

Comment: The thing is that you need to be strict with limit interpretation. If the outcome of a limit has to be finite, then there is no counter example. However, if infinity is allowed as a limit answer then Abdallah's answer suffices as a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take $a_n=(-1)^nn+\frac{1}{n}$

and

$b_n=(-1)^nn$.

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0$

and
$a_n \neq b_n$.

here, the limits don't exist.

Comment: But the limits are equal

Comment: Yeah I should have thought about it, thanks

Comment: Even the 1/n is not necessary right?

Comment: @Sorfosh to make them different.

Comment: Well yeah but since the limit does not exist we might as well set an=bn=(-1)^n since the limit does not exist

Comment: @Sorfosh just to have two different sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $a_n$ which does not converge and let $b_n := a_n$.

If $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ are well-defined, then the statement is in fact true.

Comment: The question is, when it is false, not when it's true

Comment: @Sorfosh Do you know how to read? It's true if both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge. Note that if one of them converges, the other one does as well. Otherwise it's false.

Comment: You are saying it is false without a proof. I would like to understand.. and say an=bn=n they don it converge yet the statement is true, so it is possible that both are divergent yet the statement is true